# how to set focus to an input element when page gets scroll in ios?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on a project based on angular and ionic. I have a page consisting of sign up form. It has four fields namely email,mobile no, password and confirm password.The issue I am facing is that when I tap on confirm password field then keypad gets open and page gets scrolled. then confirm password field loses its focus. cursor is not get set to that field as well as whatever I typed on keyboard is not get shown in field unless I click outside.

Comment: Alternatively you can add some margin or padding at bottom of form when keyboard is open.

Comment: @ hva.narola : I think you didn't get my issue. I am able to see the confirm password input field. it is above the keyboard. the problem is that, cursor is not there in the field as well as whatever I am typing is not visible

Comment: is it hiding under accessory bar ?

Comment: no..  it is not hiding under accessory bar.

Comment: @pritamkale update your question with html code..!